# Disable white background of pasted text in PowerPoint

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint

When I paste text from another source with "Keep source formatting option" into PowerPoint 2010 I receive a white background, that I don't want.

[image: pasted text with white background]

How can I make this text background transparent, so there would be just red text on purple?

Answer (score 2):

I would say that the problem is probably that you are not copying from Notepad/text only but a font aware application, and the source has a white background - so, it is just doing its job.

I would recommend you simply paste, then change the text's background to transparent.

Alternatively, when you paste, try a different option other than match source.

Answer (score 0):

When you right click and select "Paste" there should be several options, pick "Pest Special"  It will give you choices on how to paste text with different formatting.  It will allow you to drop fonts/backgrounds/text color/etc...

Comment: I guess some amount of pest control is in order here! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late reply, but it might interest someone with the same problem...
I pasted the text in word preserving the source theme, then select it and in Home > Font, I removed the Text Highlight Color.
Then, copy again and paste in Powerpoint while preserving source theme, and no more background.

Answer (score -1):

select merge formatting when pasting