# How to change text background color in PowerPoint 2013

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2013

I need to make presentation and paste there some code blocks from Visual Studio and preserve the text formating. Unfortunately when I paste it with keeping the format, the text has white background. Where can I change it to transparent?

[image: Pasted text background]

Comment: Suggestion:  Put an example PPT/PPTX of this on Dropbox/SkyDrive/OneDrive/Whatever so we can download it and examine what's in the file.

Comment: If they are copied in as images the only answer is to change the background color in VS (I have no idea if that can be done) If on the other hand they are copied in as text boxes just modify the background color of the text box...or to be lazy, change the background color of the presentation to white...

Comment: Also, very similar question, this may be valid as it specifically pertains to Visual Studio.  http://superuser.com/questions/576192/how-can-i-disable-a-white-background-of-a-pasted-text-in-powerpoint?rq=1